# dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/liblua.5.1.5.dylib

Tags: macos, lua, homebrew

I got the following error while trying to invoke terminal Vim (terminal app from MacVim directory); after I updated `homebrew`, `rvm` & reinstalled a new version of `Ruby`.

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/liblua.5.1.5.dylib
  Referenced from: /Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/Vim
  Reason: image not found
```

Note: Was able to solve it, so  thought I would record if someone stumbles on the same issue.

Comment: For others finding their way here for the same reason: I got this kind of error trying to open Vim while I was updating a bunch of things in Homebrew. All I had to do is wait – when it finished with its updates, everything worked again.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem seems to because `homebrew` somehow removed the old version of `lua` that was required for `Vim` to run.

So installed the specific version from `homebrew` like this:

1. Search `homebrew` for available formulae: `brew search lua`; got:

   `lua
   lua51
   luabind
   luajit
   luarocks
   homebrew/nginx/lua-nginx-module`
2. Installed: `brew install lua51`

This solved the issue. I am posting it may be able solve other brew related issues connected with installing different versions of packages.

Answer (score 12):

I use vim installed by homebrew ,my solution is reinstall vim

run 
`brew reinstall vim`

Comment: Does reinstall require that added install flags like `--with-lua` be supplied again?

Comment: I didn't add any flag , I think it's unnecessary

Answer (score 3):

I had the similar message:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/lua/lib/liblua.5.2.dylib
```

Switching version helped to me:

```
$ brew switch lua 5.2.1
    Error: lua does not have a version "5.2.1" in the Cellar.
    Versions available: 5.2.4_1, 5.2.4_3, 5.2.4_4, 5.3.4_2
$ brew switch lua 5.2.4_4
    Cleaning /usr/local/Cellar/lua/5.3.4_2
    Cleaning /usr/local/Cellar/lua/5.2.4_3
    Cleaning /usr/local/Cellar/lua/5.2.4_4
    Cleaning /usr/local/Cellar/lua/5.2.4_1
    71 links created for /usr/local/Cellar/lua/5.2.4_4
```

Comment: Instead of switch, brew now recommends to use `brew link lua@5.4` or similar.

Answer (score 1):

Error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/lua/lib/liblua.5.2.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/vim
  Reason: image not found
[1]    30835 abort      vim
```

Attempt:

`brew switch lua 5.2`

Error:

```
Error: lua does not have a version "5.2" in the Cellar.
Versions available: 5.2.4_4, 5.3.4_2
```

Solution:

`brew switch lua 5.2.4_4`

VIM running fine

Answer (score 1):

In case your problem is caused by `vi` not being able to be found as editor. With an error like this:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/ruby/lib/libruby.2.7.dylib
Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/vi
Reason: image not found
error: vi died of signal 6
error: There was a problem with the editor 'vi'.
```

It can be solved by setting Git's editor to `vim`:

```
git config --global core.editor $(which vim)
```

[Here's the discussion](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim/issues/167) where I got the solution to this case.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run:

```
brew link lua
```

to see if that works.

Alternatively:

```
brew link --overwrite lua
```

Answer (score 0):

```
➜ sudo vi
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/lua/lib/liblua.5.2.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/vi
  Reason: image not found
[1]    29504 abort      sudo vi
```

It's because old version of lua that was required for Vim to run.

`brew switch lua 5.2.4_4`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I do the following steps, it's ok.

> 1. brew uninstall vim
> 2. brew install v